Why are references to methods and classes displayed differently?
What I want (example of a member):

What I often see (example of a class):

How do I configure Visual Studio so that references to members and classes are always displayed in place, as strings, and not as a small shortcut to an additional window? It would be much more convenient.
I have tried the Intellisense settings, but they do not affect this, moreover, such a link display appears randomly and for various methods and classes.

I've never seen that little link icon before, but I don't use this feature much. Try looking under "CodeLens" in settings. These little reference lookups are part of that system.

What version of Visual Studio are you using? I just turned on CodeLens to see what it looks like for me and I'm unable to recreate this. Can you also share a screenshot of what results you get when you click the icon in the popup for the class? I'm wondering if the reference it's finding is somehow not normal.

Knowing that this is CodeLens allowed me to find several issues users submitted mentioning this behavior. Here's one of them that shows it was supposedly fixed in 16.9. There are links to some of the other reports in there. If you're on any of those versions I suggest making sure Visual Studio is up to date.

I used Visual Studio 2022 v17.11 and PRE-v17.12, the problem manifests itself on both of them. Clicking on this small icon opens a large window with all the links to this method or class, clicking on which you can go to the place where it is called. It works fine, I can click on the links in the window that opens, the problem is that it is very slow and inconvenient, and I would really like the links to be selected in the drop-down list right above the name of the method or class.
Thanks!

I also tried the CodeLens settings, but changing them did not affect the appearance of these small shortcuts. They also disappear for a while after restarting Visual Studio, and begin to appear as a drop-down list, but after a while some of them turn back into small shortcuts. To be honest, I have been using Visual Studio for more than three years, and all this time this problem persists, and every time I do not know how to solve it, except by temporarily restarting Visual studio

And yes, it doesn't matter if it's a reference to a class, method, field or something else, in all cases, a shortcut to another window appears with a random probability, instead of a drop-down list

This makes me really glad I don't use CodeLens... Given the number of issues I found reported for different versions of Visual Studio I'm guessing this is one of those things that will keep coming back. Your best chance at a fix is probably submitting an issue of your own with Microsoft.

Thanks for the advice, I created a ticket here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Why-are-references-to-methods-and-classe/10775995

For this issue, i would suggest you to check the following suggestions to troubleshoot:

Is just that specific method/class having an issue, or are all methods in that class/all classes in your project broken? Please try to create a new project and add a class/method to verify it.

Did you install any third-party extensions(e.g: Resharper/AWS Toolkit for .NET Refactoring VS Extension) previously? If yes, please disable them from Extensions->Manager Extensions

Delete .vs folder in your solution and reopen it.

If the issue persists, please consider updating your VS to the latest version(17.11.5) to see if it works.



It appears in all the projects that I open, in random places and at random times, there is no connection between them. I used version 17.11 and pre-17.12 with Net.9, this problem persists in all versions of Visual Studio that I have been using and have been using for the past three years (all the time I use VisualStudio). This problem is not tied to classes, methods, fields, or some other type, a shortcut instead of a drop-down list appears in random places wherever you can see such links.

I did a quick test on  17.11.5 and pre-17.12 but CodeLens works well. As @Logarr said, you may report this issue at Visual Studio Forum to get assistance.

Thanks for the advice, I created a ticket here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Why-are-references-to-methods-and-classe/10775995

Thanks for sharing the ticket link here. I've voted the ticket that you submitted. You can follow up that ticket to get updates.
